# iOS development certificates Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, certificate

I am facing an issue while creating iOS development certificates. I have created only one development certificate for my app on apple developers account, and the limit of generating development certificates exceeded. Why its limit exceeded, I just create only one development before.
Any one can Help me out.

[image]

Comment: Why you need more development certificates?

Comment: Include the image in the post

Comment: @arturdev because I have two apps, so I need certificates for both of them

Comment: @EdChum image is already attached.

Comment: You don’t have to create a new certificate for each app. You can reuse the existing one for all your apps!

Answer (score 0):

For each application, you need to create different App which have unique *bundle id*.  Using this *bundle id* you can create *provisioning profile* where you need to select this already created *certificate*.

```
One certifiate can sign any number of provisioning profiles which are what you need to run the app on devices.
```